# CRYSTAL REPORTS: Show horizontal data in a DETAILS section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-server

Hi Stackoverflow people

My problem is I want to show a DataTable in a horizontal way, I mean, instead of showing data from top to bottom, show them from left to right. And to accomplish that I followed the next blog:

http://vinodkotiya.blogspot.mx/2011/09/crystal-report-show-data-horizontally.html

And the result is the following:

[image]

As you can see, the last boxes are cropped. I don't know if Crystal Reports has a right margin or something like to leave a blank space there.

Comment: You can change the page margins and the page sizes to accommodate the boxes, otherwise they will cross the page boundary onto another sheet. Is that what you're asking? The only problem is that if you change to, say, a legal page size then if you try to print on a standard page size it might cross the page boundary anyway.

Comment: Have you tried a cross-tab?  It will generated additional pages as needed.

Comment: Cross-tab is a good idea, but if you dont want to use it, you can try to format dedails section in multiple column look. You can set it in Section Expert tool